# Migrating and seeding a database dynamically using Knex?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js

I am using Knex.js in my Node application in order to communicate with my MySQL database. I want to build my app to the point where the user can define what columns they want to create a table with in my app. My question is how would I go about creating the migrations for the database dynamically because I won't know columns my user wants in their table. And when I create migrations via Knex (using `knex migrate:object`), I have to specify the constraints of the table using the migration file that is automatically generated. Is there a way I can programatically implement the process of migrating the database and seeding with whatever the user provides?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a really bad idea. Try to google + read something about dynamic schema modification anti pattern.

That being said you cannot use knex's migrations/populate framework for that. Just call knex.schema.* methods directly from your application code.